# Client and server communication using select can't send and receive from each other with C

Tags: c, sockets, select, tcp, send

In our project we have to make a game (that is already done) and allow a multiplayer way to play (with a P2P method). I have made "client" and "server" programs to begin (I think that in the future the programs will be the same) using the select method in order to allow them to send and receive messages to each other. When I tried to send a message (a number written in the terminal) from the server to the client, it's ok, but, when I tried to do the same from the client to the server, nothing happened. Moreover, when I start sending a message from the client to the server, it works but the server can't send nothing (more precisely the client doesn't receive anything).

I don't understand this behaviour, and so I've tried to use threads but my profesor said that I don't need it if I use well select...

You will find below the code for the "server"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>   
#include <arpa/inet.h>    
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/time.h> 
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

typedef struct Element Element;
struct Element
{
    int data_i;
    Element *suivant;
};

typedef struct
{
    Element *premier;
} File;

void initialise(File *file)
{
    file->premier = NULL;
}

int enfiler(File *file, long long nbre)
{
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Il faut initialiser la file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    Element *new_el = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    new_el->suivant = NULL;

    new_el->data_i = nbre;

    if (file->premier != NULL)
    {
        Element *elementActuel = file->premier;
        while (elementActuel->suivant != NULL)
        {
            elementActuel = elementActuel->suivant;
        }
        elementActuel->suivant = new_el;
        printf("j'ai bien enfilé le message\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else
    {
        file->premier = new_el;
        printf("j'ai bien enfilé le message\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

Element defiler(File *file)
{
    if (file != NULL && file->premier != NULL)
    {
        Element *el = malloc(sizeof(Element));
        el = file->premier;
        file->premier = file->premier->suivant;
        free (el);
        return *el;
    }
    //voir quoi retourner lors d'erreurs
}

void stop(char * msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

typedef struct {
    int fd;
}client_info;
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    //Variables

    int opt = TRUE;
    int master_socket=0, new_socket=0, max_client = 30, activity=0, i=0;
    int max_sd = 0;
    client_info client_tab[max_client];

    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int addr_len=0;
    fd_set readfds;

    long long message=0;
    int64_t buffer=0;
    int smess = 0;

    int sd =0;
    write(0,"initialisation\n",15);
    //initializing the "file"
    File file_mess, file_recus;
    initialise(&file_mess);
    initialise(&file_recus);

    //Initializing files descriptors
    for (i = 0; i < max_client; i++) 
    {
        client_tab[i].fd = -1;
    }

    //create a master socket
    if( (master_socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0)) == 0) 
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 
    if( setsockopt(master_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //Initializing address
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &address.sin_addr);
    address.sin_port = htons( 1234 );
    addr_len = sizeof(address);


    //Configurating master_socket to listen to new connections . 
    if(bind(master_socket,(const struct sockaddr *)&address,addr_len)<0) stop("binding error");

    if(listen(master_socket,3)<0) stop("Problem initializing master_socket");
    printf("Enterring while\n");
    while(TRUE){
        //clear the socket set
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
 
        //add master socket to set
        FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO,&readfds);
        max_sd = master_socket;
        
        //add child sockets to set
        for ( i = 0 ; i < max_client ; i++) 
        {
            //socket descriptor
            sd = client_tab[i].fd;
            
            //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list
            if(sd > 0)
                FD_SET( sd , &readfds);
            
            //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function
            if(sd > max_sd)
                max_sd = sd;
        }
        
        activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);

        if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR)) stop("select error");

        if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds)) 
        {
            if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addr_len))<0) stop("accepting problem");

            for (i = 0; i < max_client; i++) 
            {
                //if position is empty
                if( client_tab[i].fd == -1 )
                {
                    client_tab[i].fd = new_socket;
                    printf("Adding to list of sockets as %d\n\n" , i);
                    // Après avoir ajouté le client dans le tableau, le serveur lui renvoie un id (valeur de i)
                    if(send(client_tab[i].fd, &i, sizeof(int), 0) == -1) stop("recv() : envoi de l'id");
                    break;
                }
                
            }

        }
//else its some IO operation on some other socket :)
        for (i = 0; i < max_client; i++) 
        {
            sd = client_tab[i].fd;
             
            if (FD_ISSET( sd , &readfds) && sd!=-1) 
            {
                //Check if it was for closing , and also read the incoming message
                if ((smess = recv( sd,(char *)&buffer,__SIZEOF_LONG_LONG__,0)) == 0)
                {
                    //Somebody disconnected , get his details and print
                    getpeername(sd , (struct sockaddr*)&address , (socklen_t*)&addr_len);
                    printf("%i disconnected.\n",i);
                    //Close the socket and mark as 0 in list for reuse
                    close( sd );
                    client_tab[i].fd = -1;

                }
                else{
                    message = ntohl(buffer);
                    buffer=0;
                    printf("Message reçu de %i : %lli\n",i,message);
                    enfiler (&file_recus, message);
                    message = 0;
                }

            }
        }
if(FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO,&readfds)){
            scanf("%lli",&message);
            enfiler(&file_mess,message);
            buffer = htonl(file_mess.premier->data_i);
            for (i = 0; i < max_client; i++)
            {
                if(client_tab[i].fd != -1) send(client_tab[i].fd,&buffer,sizeof(buffer),0);
            }
            printf("J'ai bien envoyé : %lli\n",message);
            defiler(&file_mess);
            buffer = 0;
            message=0;
        }
        if (file_mess.premier != NULL)
        {
            printf("regarde si des trucs à envoyer\n");
            buffer = htonl(file_mess.premier->data_i);
            //envoie à tout le monde
            for (i = 0; i < max_client; i++)
            {
                if (client_tab[i].fd != -1)
                {
                    send(client_tab[i].fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                }
            }
            printf("envoyé\n");
            defiler(&file_mess);
            buffer=0;
        }

    }   
}
```

And here the "client" :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define BUFSIZE 100
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct Element Element;
struct Element
{
    int data_i;
    Element *suivant;
};

typedef struct
{
    Element *premier;
} File;

void initialise(File *file)
{
    file->premier = NULL;
}

int enfiler(File *file, long long nbre)
{
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Il faut initialiser la file");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    Element *new_el = malloc(sizeof(Element));
    new_el->suivant = NULL;

    new_el->data_i = nbre;

    if (file->premier != NULL)
    {
        Element *elementActuel = file->premier;
        while (elementActuel->suivant != NULL)
        {
            elementActuel = elementActuel->suivant;
        }
        elementActuel->suivant = new_el;
        printf("j'ai bien enfilé le message\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else
    {
        file->premier = new_el;
        printf("j'ai bien enfilé le message\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

Element defiler(File *file)
{
    if (file != NULL && file->premier != NULL)
    {
        Element *el = malloc(sizeof(Element));
        el = file->premier;
        file->premier = file->premier->suivant;
        free(el);
        return *el;
    }
 
}

void stop(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    //Creating a TCP|IPV4 socket
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd == -1)
        stop("Probleme de socket");

    //Creating the socket

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1234);
    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr);

    //initializing the "file"
    File file_mess, file_recus;
    initialise(&file_mess);
    initialise(&file_recus);

    //initiliazing the file descriptor set
    fd_set readfds;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);

    if (connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        stop("Connection error");
    int id = 0;
    if(recv(sockfd, &id, sizeof(int), 0) == -1) stop ("recv() : reception de l'id"); // Le client récupère son id
    printf("Mon id : %i\n", id);

    FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfds);

    //Variables
    int nSelect = 0;
    int n;
    long long mess = 0;
    int64_t fmess = 0;
    while (TRUE)
    {
        nSelect = select(sockfd + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (nSelect < 0)
            stop("Select error");
        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfds))
        {
            scanf("%lli", &mess);
            fmess = htonl(mess);
            send(sockfd, &fmess, sizeof(fmess), 0);
            printf("J'ai bien envoyé : %lli\n", mess);
            mess = 0;
        }
        if (file_mess.premier != NULL)
        {
            send(sockfd, &file_mess.premier->data_i, sizeof(file_mess.premier->data_i), 0);
            defiler(&file_mess);
        }
        if (FD_ISSET(sockfd, &readfds))
        { 
            printf("reçu\n");
            if ((n=recv(sockfd, &mess, sizeof(long long), 0)) < 0)
                stop("recv(");
            else if (n==0)
            {
                printf("déconnexion...\n");
                close(sockfd);
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("cc\n");
                mess = ntohl(fmess);
                fmess = 0;
                printf("Message reçu: %lli\n", mess);
                enfiler(&file_recus, mess);
                mess = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Here, you will find my tests:

1-The client begins the conversation by sending 13, but doesn't receive what the server tries to send

[**client**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIqpA.png)

[**server**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od5lH.png)

2-Then, the server begins the conversation sending 15, the client doesn't receive it and he sends nothing

[**client, before stopping**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vHwp.png)

[**server, before stopping**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqYid.png)

[**client, stopped**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq8wY.png)

[**server, stopped**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkbgf.png)

PS: the use of file is to allow a good treatment for the data (I will made a protocol [using long long numbers] and so I will have to process the data before sending and after receiving). And to finish, this code also permits to give a number to identify the players (and to know who the data receive is for).

Comment: Unfortunately this is too much code for Stack Overflow. You need to reduce this to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Not only for the sake of posting on SO but reducing to an MRE is also a standard debugging technique.

Comment: Your client is not resetting `readfds` on every call to `select()`, like the server is. So, if `select()` ever exits when `sockfd` has no data ready (ie, because of keyboard input on STDIN) then `sockfd` will be removed from `readfds` and `select()` will never detect any subsequent data on `sockfd`. You need to reset `fd_set`s *every* time you call `select()`.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output LOTS of warning messages.  When compiling, enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std-gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding: `typedef struct
{
    Element *premier;
} File;`   This struct does not have a `tag` name.  Most debuggers use the tag name to access the fields within the struct.  Strongly suggest using a `tag` name

Comment: regarding the function: `Element defiler(File *file)`  This function fails to return a `Element` when the `IF()` fails.  so the caller of that function has no indication of the failure AND the caller fails to check the returned value

Comment: the posted code is missing the error checking for `send()` and `recv()` so how is the code to know if the operation was successful or not?

Comment: suggest reading: [client-server](https://www.binarytides.com/server-client-example-c-sockets-linux/)

Comment: `free (el);` and then `return *el;`?!?!  That's accessing memory after `free()`'ing it, and it's undefined behavior.